# Validate request and display error messages when there is no previous page

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have the following function in my Laravel 9 application:

```
Route::get('/update-appointment-status/{uuid}/{status}', [App\Http\Controllers\LeadController::class, 'updateAppointmentStatus'])->name('update-appointment-status');


public function updateAppointmentStatus(Request $request, LeadService $leadService, string $uuid, int $status)
{
    $validation = $request->validate([
        'uuid' => ['required', 'uuid'],
        'status' => ['required', 'numeric', Rule::in(Lead::STATUSES)],
    ]);
    
    $lead = Lead::where('uuid', $uuid)->firstOrFail();

    $leadService->updateStatus($lead, $status);

    return view('leads.update-status')->with(compact('lead'));
}
```

The link is accessed from inside emails, which means there is no "previous page". How can I display the error messages inside my view? Right now the app gets redirected to the base URL where there is a validation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to create a "Form Request Validation", you can learn on how to implement this using the Laravel documention:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation

Then after you created you form request validation, you can define the redirect URL using the `$redirect` property and put it inside your form request validation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#customizing-the-redirect-location

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class SomeRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * The URI that users should be redirected to if validation fails.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirect = '/path-to-page';

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'uuid' => ['required', 'uuid'],
            'status' => ['required', 'numeric', Rule::in(Lead::STATUSES)],
        ];
    }
}
```